# django не дает писать логи

Tags: python, django

Сделал настройки в settings

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{asctime} {message}',
            'style': '{',
            'datefmt': '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
        },
        'standard': {
            # levelname)s   %(pathname)s   %(funcName
            'format': '%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(message)s',
            # 'style': '{',
            'datefmt': '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file_error': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/error.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'file_rotate': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/info.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file_rotate'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django_error': {
            'handlers': ['file_error'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Потом делаю в скрипте при запросе
в ModelView

```
    log = logging.getLogger('django') или 'django_error' все равно пусто
    log.info(s)  # s какая то строка
```

Файл создается но пустой. ничего нет. Молча, ошибок нет.
права на папке логов 777

Хотя если тоже самое делаю через command
python manager.py command
То в логе записи появляются я вижу и 'django' и 'django_error' отрабатывают

Еще заметил django тут успешно свои логи пишет.
Смотрю там появились логи что CRF токен там неверный... вобщем вроде лог работает. Но почему я писать не могу...

**UPD**

Вобщем я понял, что если лог текст на латинице - пишет в лог. Не пишет если там текст русские буквы. причем делал и так и так:

```
log.info('1 test!', request.user)
log.info(u'2 привет', request.user)
log.info('3 Здарова!', request.user)
```

Пишет только первую строчку. Остальные 2 пропускает. Без ошибок, молча.

Может сталкивался кто? что можно сделать?
Работает на сервере ubuntu python 3.6

На windows 10 python 3.6 локально все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вобщем достаточно было добавить  **'encoding': 'utf-8'** в handlers

```
'handlers': {
        'file_rotate': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/info.log'),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'encoding': 'utf-8',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
    },
```